# What is this connector

Tags: outlet

I’ve been trying to figure out what this connector is and everyone has no clue. There isn’t enough identifying information to find anything on google. All I see is a label “lwai”. It’s located in a panel with power outlets, rj45 jacks, and some audio jacks. I think I found that it might be related to some hvac system but I can’t find any description or picture that confirms that. [image: mystery connector]

Comment: do you have a wider picture of what this is? I may be able to find the exact plug.

Comment: More context about what the connector is attached to could be useful in providing more specific answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the keys in the socket, I don't think that it is meant for a trailer power cable. It seems to be a dock connector to supply a docked boat with power.

[image]

Picture comes from [this](http://www.downwindmarine.com/Dock-Connectors-Hubbell-Plugs-and-Receptacles-120-208V-p-90891076.html) page.

Comment: I agree, you can see the thread around the edge...

Comment: I also agree with this.

Answer (score 3):

It's an IEC pin and sleeve connector, based on color, pins and ground position it should be 3 phase 120/208V.  Google iec pin and sleeve and you'll find mfr guides.

Answer (score 3):

This is a 3 phase power connector with neutral and earth according to the IEC 60309. It's made for 120V/208-144V/250V 50-60Hz Systems. The contact in the top should be ground. The contact in the center could be a pilot contact which might indicate a 63A connector

Comment: What makes you say this? It surely is a 3 phase connector

Comment: I think you are right they come in many sockets.

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be an industrial plug power, I saw something similar in a milk factory. That can provide highter voltage than a regular plug.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_and_multiphase_power_plugs_and_sockets

Comment: Specifically a ["16 A 240 V 3P+E+N 9h socket"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60309#/media/File:CEE_3P%2BN%2BPE_230V.jpg).

Comment: The only reason they provide a higher voltage, is because the phase-to-phase voltage is higher than the phase-to-neutral voltage. E.g. for a normal 220 or 240 Volt lines, the phase to phase-voltage is around 400V. (an increase equal to the square-toot of 3, to be exact).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a connection for a trailer picture below.

[image]